# Problem retrieving text file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I write the text file to de Documents folder with the following code:

```
NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *fileDocumentsDirectory = [filePaths objectAtIndex:0];    
NSString *fullPath = [fileDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.fileName];
NSData *tmpData = [NSData dataWithBytes:self.content length:[self.content length]];
[tmpData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

If i create a string directly with the contents of NSData, it works, so the data seems ok. And i retrieve the file with:

```
NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
```

or

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

or into an NSData and from there to a String with

```
NSData *fileContentsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileContentsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In both cases, fileContents is null. I'm going insane, i just can't see why fileContents is null. I checked every value with NSLog and "self.content" contains values, NSData contains the same values... but trying to retrieve them returns null OR, trying with say NSUTF16StringEncoding, i retrieve... chinese characters, but not null.

It must be something encoding-related, but tmpData uses UTF-8 and initializing a String from it it works like a charm, the problem seems to be when i read/write to a file.

I'm dizzy by now, can you give me a hand?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I've just tried to open a .txt file from an URL, with the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:tmpField.text];
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req
                                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                                 error:&error];
if(response == nil) {
    // TO BE CONTINUED           
}
NSInteger statusCode = [response statusCode];
NSString *contentType = [[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];

if(statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300 && [contentType hasPrefix:@"text"]) {
    NSString *payloadAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I've checked and the program reaches the last line, but payloadAsString is... that's right, also nil. So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try reading the file with NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding for a change - just happened to me, exactly the same symptoms.

Comment: Following this advise, being the content of the string "OAOAk", what i recieve is "`+Ì". I'm loosing my mind over this, it doesn't makes sense because i'm not changing the encoding anywhere, "self.content" it's just an UITextView.text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's `self.content`'s type? If it's an `NSString` then use the `-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` method instead of `-[NSData initWithBytes:]` to get your `NSData` object.

Comment: Hey, it worked! Thanks. Now, i'm still having the same issue when loading a text file from an url. Any clue there? Because there i'm retrieving the NSData with NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error]; and the String with NSString *payloadAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];. Thanks again!

Comment: At that point I would opt to make use of the (widely-used and recommended) HTTP request library ASIHTTPRequest. I use it myself and there are no response encoding issues, because it stores the response data internally as both NSData and NSString objects. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest for more info on it and download links.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If i give it a try right now my girlfriend will kick me out from home (and it's quite cold) so i'll bookmark it to see it tomorrow.